# Can a process have more then 1 page tables?

Tags: virtual-memory, page-tables

I was given a question in a quiz "A process size is 2^6+^2^12+2^23 bytes and total memory size of system is 4GB page size is 4k, how many page tables are there how many page directories and pages ? Assume that initially all memory was free ?
How to solve this ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. It is a computer architecture question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a process have more then 1 page tables?

Yes, some systems use multiple page tables. On the VAX, e.g., each process has three page tables.

> how many page tables are there

Entirely system specific

> how many page directories

Entirely system specific. Some systems do not even use page directories.

> how many [] pages

Add the page size to the process size and divide by the page size.